# Too many iterations in filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I create a filter to get the name of a building by id:

```
app.filter('getBuilding', function( APIService ) {

    return function(input) {

        var buildings = APIService.query({ route:'building', id: input }, function(building) {

            return building.name;

        });

    };

});
```

The example give me an iteration error. Is it a ng-repeat update problem? How can I prevent this?

```
<li ng-repeat="room in rooms" class="list-group-item">
   <strong>{{room.name}}</strong><span class="small">( {{room.building | getBuilding}} )</span>
</li>
```

thanks!

Comment: If you don't show us the controller in which you're binding your `rooms` array, we cannot help you. Also, if you could provide a working Plunker, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Filters should be used to format data for the display. You are expected to return a primitive (a string or number) from filter function to display that value.

There are several problems with your code:

1. Your filter function does not return anything. Because filter does not return any value, angularJS keeps iterating waiting for a value. After iteration limit is reached, error is thrown.
2. Your service uses callbacks. The only way for this to work in theory would be returning a promise object from `APIService`. But as far as I know, filters do not work in async fashion and do not resolve promises. You have to return a value at once for filter to work correctly.
3. A filter function may be invoked many times until model stabilizes in scope changes. This means using remote calls in filter can have drastic performance issues.

The correct way would be loading building's name in controller or directive and then passing that value to filter, if the name needs to be formatted in any way.